# VBA to select sheet based on cell value of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

On Sheet 1(viva-2) Row 11 has a drop-down(validation) with yes/no.
By default, value will be "no" and sheet 11(Manage-d) cell range A11:D30 should be disabled/locked.
Selecting "Yes", user should be able to select Sheet11(Manage-d) and cells from range A11:D30 should be unlocked.

I am new to VBA, but I am putting my effort to learn.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


    Dim RNG                         As Range


    If Target.Row = 11 Then
     If Range("11").Value = "YES" Then
            Sheets("Manage-d").Select
            Sheets("Manage-d").Range("A11:D30").Locked = False
            Sheets("Manage-d").Range("A11:D30").Activate
        Else
             Sheets("Manage-d").Range("A11:D30").Locked = True
     End If
    End If
```

Comment: Range("11") isn't a valid range reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the `Worksheet_Change` instead of the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` so that the user doesn't have to ciack another cell to trigger the macro.

Assuming the drop-down(validation) is in `Range("A11")`:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A11")) Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Manage-d")

            .Range("A11:D30").Locked = (UCase(Target.Value) = "NO")

            If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
                Application.Goto .Range("A11:D30"), True
            End If

        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Range object represents a single cell or a range of cells.This code is working for me

```
 If Range("A1").Value = "YES" Then '' Range A1 is the first cell
        Sheets("Manage-d").Select
        Sheets("Manage-d").Range("A11:D30").Locked = False
        Sheets("Manage-d").Range("A11:D30").Activate
    Else
         Sheets("Manage-d").Range("A11:D30").Locked = True
 End If
```

Comment: @Thomas Inzina, I have 2 concerns with the code you provided.               1. Its working as expected, cells are enabled/unlocked when the drop down value is yes. I can input the data, but the problem is its not highlighting the cell when I click on it (On Sheet Manage-d) 2. Is it possible to throw a prompt to the user to change the drop down value, when he tries to click on locked cells when the value of drop down is "NO"

Comment: @Thomas Inzina, do you want me to post an other question? as this question is answered.

Comment: I think it make sense to post new question. Hence I have posted an other question as per policies. Please help if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776578/vba-to-disable-sheet-based-on-cell-value